# Парсинг html webBroswer

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser, парсер

Стоит следующая задача - получить динамически подгружаемые данные на странице. На странице используется аякс, который подгружает таблицу. Нужно эту таблицу получить.
Попытался использовать WebBrowser :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
     Thread thread = new Thread(Start);
     thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     thread.Start();
        }

     private static void Start()
            {
                WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

                Uri address = new Uri("url");
                wb.DocumentCompleted+=wb_DocumentCompleted;
                wb.Navigate(address);
            }

    private static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                var wb = sender as WebBrowser;
                if(wb == null)
                    return;

                var text = wb.Document;
            }
```

Однако событие DocumentCompleted не отрабатывает(хендлер не дергается). Подскажите пожалуйста, что тому причиной? А также хотелось бы узнать, правильно ли вообще решать такую задачу с помощью WebBrowser

Comment: А если WebBrowser не в отдельном потоке запускать, а в родном гуевом (форма WinForms)?

Comment: Честно говоря - не пробовал. Однако мне гуевое приложение как таковое не нужно, нужно просто эмулировать. Проблема может быть связана с этим?

Comment: Смотрите [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4269800/5045688). Напрямую `DocumentCompleted` не работает. Но обходной способ есть.

Comment: Огромное Вам человеческое спасибо! Осталось только понять, как найти прогруженные данные